# Inibir informações RequiredRoleInterceptor no log do demoiselle

Tags: java, demoiselle

Ao utilizar o framework demoiselle, a cada interação do usuário, o sistema regista a informação `br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredRoleInterceptor` no log do servidor.
Os logs ficam extremamente grandes devido à quantidade de informações.

Eu gostaria de inibir essa informação do log.

Tem como fazer isso?

```
20:44:11,015 INFO  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredRoleInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Verificando se o usu?rio 1A1 possui a(s) role(s): [*]
20:44:11,031 INFO  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredRoleInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Verificando se o usu?rio 1A1 possui a(s) role(s): [*]
20:44:11,051 INFO  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredRoleInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Verificando se o usu?rio 1A1 possui a(s) role(s): [*]
20:44:11,073 INFO  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredRoleInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Verificando se o usu?rio 1A1 possui a(s) role(s): [*]
20:44:11,091 INFO  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredRoleInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Verificando se o usu?rio 1A1 possui a(s) role(s): [*]
20:44:11,112 INFO  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredRoleInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Verificando se o usu?rio 1A1 possui a(s) role(s): [*]
20:44:11,270 INFO  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredRoleInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Verificando se o usu?rio 1A1 possui a(s) role(s): [*]
20:44:11,295 INFO  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredRoleInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Verificando se o usu?rio 1A1 possui a(s) role(s): [*]
20:44:11,390 INFO  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredRoleInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Verificando se o usu?rio 1A1 possui a(s) role(s): [*]
20:44:11,418 INFO  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredRoleInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Verificando se o usu?rio 1A1 possui a(s) role(s): [*]
20:44:11,459 INFO  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredRoleInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Verificando se o usu?rio 1A1 possui a(s) role(s): [*]
20:44:11,493 INFO  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredRoleInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Verificando se o usu?rio 1A1 possui a(s) role(s): [*]
20:44:11,509 INFO  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredRoleInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Verificando se o usu?rio 1A1 possui a(s) role(s): [*]
20:44:11,548 INFO  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredRoleInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Verificando se o usu?rio 1A1 possui a(s) role(s): [*]
20:44:11,573 INFO  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredRoleInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Verificando se o usu?rio 1A1 possui a(s) role(s): [*]
20:44:11,633 INFO  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredRoleInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Verificando se o usu?rio 1A1 possui a(s) role(s): [*]
20:44:11,687 INFO  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredRoleInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Verificando se o usu?rio 1A1 possui a(s) role(s): [*]
20:44:11,714 INFO  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredRoleInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Verificando se o usu?rio 1A1 possui a(s) role(s): [*]
20:44:11,737 INFO  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredRoleInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Verificando se o usu?rio 1A1 possui a(s) role(s): [*]
20:44:11,779 INFO  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredRoleInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Verificando se o usu?rio 1A1 possui a(s) role(s): [*]
20:44:12,207 INFO  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredRoleInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Verificando se o usu?rio 1A1 possui a(s) role(s): [unidade]
20:44:12,216 INFO  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredRoleInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Verificando se o usu?rio 1A1 possui a(s) role(s): [unidade]
20:44:12,303 INFO  [br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredRoleInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Verificando se o usu?rio 1A1 possui a(s) role(s): [unidade]
```

Answer (score 3):

Consegui resolver.
Basta configurar o arquivo standalone.xml no jboss.
Alterei as opções de log de INFO para WARN.